# how to convert two-dimensional list to another list with dict as elements

Tags: python, list

how to convert list1 to list2?

```
list1 =[[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
list2 = [[{1:2},{11:22}],[{3:4},{33:44}]]
```

key of list 2 is odd elements of list1, while value of list2 is even number of list1

I've tried like below, but get different list3.

```
def f(list1):

    newlist=[]
    for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
        dict1={}
        for j,key in enumerate (list1[i]):
            dict1[key]=list1[i+1][j]
            newlist.append(dict1)  
    print newlist



f(list1)
[{1: 2, 11: 22}, {1: 2, 11: 22}, {33: 44, 3: 4}, {33: 44, 3: 4}]
```

Comment: `[[1, 11],[6, 66], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]` what will be result of this sample? is 0th item is list of odd number and 1st item is list of even number(same 2nd is odd and 3rd is even)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As list comprehension:

```
list1 = [[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
list2 = [[{tup[0]: tup[1]} for tup in zip(*list1[i:i+2])] for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)]
# Prints as [[{1: 2}, {11: 22}], [{3: 4}, {33: 44}]]
```

---

Edit: This one's a bit cleaner (and more pythonic perhaps).

```
list2 = [[dict([tup]) for tup in zip(*sublist)] for sublist in zip(list1[0::2], list1[1::2])]
```

---

Edit2: The list comprehension is equivalent to this nested for-loop.

```
list1 =[[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
list2 = list()

# Iterate over list1 two by two, first round: sublist = ([1,11], [2,22])
for sublist in zip(list1[0::2], list1[1::2]):

    inner_result = list()

    # Second loop equivalent to for tup in zip(sublist[0], sublist[1])
    for tup in zip(*sublist):  # First round, tup will be (1,2) then (11, 22)    

        # Make dictionary from tuple, for first tuple this is
        # equivalent to: dict([(1,2)]) == {1: 2}
        new_dict = dict([tup])  
        inner_result.append(new_dict)

    list2.append(inner_result)
```

Comment: yeah, very clean, while I'm just begin learning python, the way is a little hard for me to think out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. The issue is here:

```
dict1={}
for j,key in enumerate (list1[i]):
  dict1[key]=list1[i+1][j]
  newlist.append(dict1)
```

In loop you're using the same dict. So to achieve what you want just move `dict1` definition into the loop (create a new dict on each iteration):

```
for j,key in enumerate (list1[i]):
  dict1={}
  dict1[key]=list1[i+1][j]
  newlist.append(dict1)
```

Comment: def f(list1):
    
    newlist=[]
    
    for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
       dict1={} 
       for j,key in enumerate (list1[i]):
            dict1[key]=list1[i+1][j]
       newlist.append([dict1])
    print newlist

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
list2 = []
ind = 0
while ind < len(list1):
    d1 = {list1[ind][0]: list1[ind+1][0]}
    d2 = {list1[ind][1]: list1[ind+1][1]}
    list2.append([d1, d2])
    ind += 2
print list2        # prints [[{1: 2}, {11: 22}], [{3: 4}, {33: 44}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create **List--> List--> dictionaries** from the given list, consider 0th item is Key from the list1 and 1st item is value.

1. Iterate every item from the `list1` by **enumerator** because we want index of every item from the `list1`.
2. Process on only those items which index is even means 0, 2, 4, ..
3. Create **list of dictionary’s** from the Current Item and Next Item of the `list1`
4. Append list of dictionary’s into `result` list.
5. **Handle exception** for Index Error.

Demo:

```
>>> list1 =[[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
>>> for i, value in enumerate(list1):
...     if i%2==0:
...         try:
...             result.append([{value[0]:list1[i+1][0]}, {value[1]:list1[i+1][1]}])
...         except IndexError:
...             print "Index Over"
...             break
... 
>>> result
[[{1: 2}, {11: 22}], [{3: 4}, {33: 44}]]
```

Comment: @Stella: Welcome !!! Free to ask questions on stackoverflow or me(check profile).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def f(lista):
    lnew = []
    i=0
    while i < len(lista):
        dict1 = {lista[i][0]:lista[i+1][0]}
        dict2 = {lista[i][1]:lista[i+1][1]}
        lnew.append([dict1,dict2])
        i += 2
    return lnew

lold = [[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
print(f(lold))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [27]: list1 =[[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
In [28]: l2 = [ zip(item, list1[k+1]) for k,item in enumerate(list1) if k +1 < len(list1) and k % 2 == 0 ]
In [29]: [[{ item[0][0]: item[1][0]}, [{item[0][1]: item[1][1] }]  ] for item in l2]
Out[29]: [[{1: 11}, [{2: 22}]], [{3: 33}, [{4: 44}]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newlist=[]

for i in range(0, len(list1), 2):
   dict1={} 
   for j,key in enumerate (list1[i]):
        dict1[key]=list1[i+1][j]
   newlist.append([dict1])
print newlist
```

update my coding, from newlist.append(dict1) under 2nd for to newnlist.append([dict1]) under 1st for